# Displaying ManyToManyField correctly in DjangoAdmin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to add a Likes model to a Posts application so that it records every time a User 'likes' a determined post. I have already added the likes field to the Posts model as a ManyToManyField and have tried to register it to display in the Django Admin, more exactly in the Post detail, but the result of the code I have only displays a list of all users where it should only be a list of the users that have liked the corresponding post.

Here's the code for my Posts model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):

    # ForeignKey that relates the post to the user that published it and their corresponding profile.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/pics')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # ManyToManyField that translates to the users that have liked the post
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.title, self.user.username)

    def get_likes(self):
        return '\n'.join([l.likes for l in self.likes.all()])
```

Also this is the code for the admin.py file.

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'pk',
        'user',
        'title',
        'photo',
        'created',
        'modified',
        'get_likes',
    )
    list_display_links = ('pk', 'title',)
    list_editable = ('photo',)
    search_fields = (
        'post__user',
        'post__title'
    )
    list_filter = (
        'created',
        'modified'
    )
    fieldsets = (
        ('Profile', {
            'fields' : (
                'user',
            )
        }),
        ('Post', {
            'fields' : (
                'title',
                'photo',
                'likes',
            )
        })
    )
```

How can I get the Django admin to display the ManyToManyField correctly in the post detail (i.e. display the users that have actually liked the post instead of a list of all users)?

Comment: Please add a screenshot

Comment: Not sure what you need a screenshot for, if the server isn't showing any errors. The admin is just showing the wrong information in that field, like I stated earlier. @AtleyVarghese